# PHP cookie into a string

Tags: php, cookies

I read that in PHP, you can view all the cookies by using print_r, according to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp .

```
<?php 
  print_r($_COOKIE); 
?>
```

But I want to do more with the content of the cookie.

Is there a way to concatenate the cookie names and values into, something like a string variable, without knowing the cookie names, instead of relying on print_r?

I couldn't find answers online. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either of these may work depending on the complexity of your cookie array

```
implode(',',$_COOKIE)

json_encode($_COOKIE)

serialize($_COOKIE)
```

I'd advise against this, and just rely on traversing the array

simple example: $_COOKIE['name']

Comment: Traversing most likely meaning using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to all coookie names, without knowing them in advance, with code like this:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
   print "Variable " . $name . " has value " . $value . "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this with all debuggin, _POST, _GET, _SESSION, _COOKIE

```
 echo "<pre>";
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $val) {
    echo "[$key] = $val \r\n";
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "is ARRAY ::::::: \"$key\" : \r\n";
        foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2) {
            echo "[$key2] = $val2 \r\n";
        }
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```